# MongoDB Query taking 2 minutes for scanning 20k records

Tags: mongodb, performance, query-optimization

Helo,

I have a mongodb collection with around 20k documents. The deleted documents are stored in the collection as well, meaning they are "soft" deleted.

**Now, i want to query the documents based on "status" key. The status can be either "open", "closed" or "deleted". I need the records with status as "closed"**

I see that the document count fulfilling my criteria is 25 only. However, the documents scanned (after applying index) are 18k.

Hence, my query takes around 2 minutes to execute and many a time, it times out.

My first questions is:
1. Should a query executing on 20k documents take so much time? 20k isn't such a huge count right?
2. Can someone guide me with optimizing the query further, if it can be? 
Pushing the deleted records in a separate archive collection is the last thing i would like to do.

Here is my current query:

**

```js
db.collectionname.find({$and: [{ $and: [{ status: {$ne: 'open'} },{ status: {$ne: 'deleted'} }] }, 
       { 'submittedDate': { $gte: new Date("2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte: new Date("2019-02-02T00:00:00.000Z") } }
       ] })
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a single field index as `{status: 1}`.  Replace the index with a compound index `{status: 1, submittedDate: 1}` will improve your performance.  20k is nothing if properly indexed.  If you have only 3 status, replace your query as follows.

```
db.collectionname.find({status: 'closed',
    'submittedDate': { $gte: new Date("2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"), 
            $lte: new Date("2019-02-02T00:00:00.000Z") }})
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Adding the index "{status: 1, submittedDate: 1}" helped considerably. The query now takes just 3 ms as compared to the earlier 93 secs.